# What is best practice purchasing a file in app billing, for example a book

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download, in-app-billing

Well for in-app billing generally I see that it is using for game components like "health", "gun" or etc. if I want to sell a file such as book or magazin or question database. which way should I prefer?

for example I have just know after billing process, start a "do in background" method for downloading a file from server. But now I dont know what will happen in future. namely, if user delete my app and want to install again. or if I update my app what will happen. user needs to buy again or what? Also a file can be huge sizes, and when downloading in background if internet is discontinuated while downloading. what will happen?

can anybody tell? As specially about my concerns.

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/2677801) for downloading file.

Answer (score 0):

when you are downloading a file, using any kind of classes for ex: `AsyncTask` class, when your download finished, and you receive all your data, than you will save it in for example .`txt` file or etc, so you do not need to worry about internet connection, because if user disconnected you will jump out of `AsyncTask`  thread, just put a try catch or etc there to check it.

but I myself prefer to use `database` instead of files, its faster, secure and you can do anything you what with you data. for more you can check this link [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) or [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/)

---

hope this help you my friend